# How to create custom view via js class for Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, custom-view

I'm using Angular 8 and [fullcalendar.io](https://fullcalendar.io).
Now I want to create custom view. 
 I connected plugin with this class and it works.
This is the link of docs: [fullcalendar with js (docs)](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js).
Could somebody write simple minimum working class of it? So then I could continue..

I would like to dayGrid like this:

[image]

but the event should look bigger and with another description[image]

Is it possible to make using just Custom view via [Settings](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-settings), or I should write with JS class? If I should write with JS class could somebody help me, please how to do it?

Comment: "Could somebody write simple minimum working class of it"...why not study the existing fullCalendar source code? All the built-in view types (e.g. timegrid, list, timeline etc) are actually written as plugins in the same kind of way. Then you can just copy one and start modifying it to your needs.

Comment: But actually, did you try the existing [list view](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view)? Because it's not so different from your screenshot, especially if you set a custom duration of one day. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBEqLpW?&editable=true&editors=001. If you can live with one of the existing views, it will save you a lot of effort writing and maintaining a custom view

Comment: Or, you might be able to achieve your goal with dayGrid just using some very simple CSS and a quick use of eventRender to add a description: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBEqLxW . I would avoid creating a custom view if you can possibly help it - it's a lot of work, and with a bit of imagination you can probably just use the existing views to get what you need.

Comment: @ADyson yeah I tried it before this.. But css in angular does not work.. If i will change just css of events in dayGridDay it will solve my problem

Comment: "css in angular does not work"....that can't be true. CSS works on HTML elements, it has nothing to do with Angular (or JavaScript in general) really. And fullCalendar is not actually written using Angular either (apart from the plugin which wraps around it). I'm guessing you did something specific which didn't work correctly - if so you should perhaps show us so that we can help with it. But I can't think of any particular reason why the CSS I've used in https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBEqLpW?&editable=true&editors=001 should not work for you, even if you also use Angular.